# Nginx no reconoce a php 7

Tags: php, mysql, web, nginx

He instalado Nginx, MySQL y PHP 7, pero cuando hago la prueba de phpinfo() solo me descarga el archivo y no lo despliega en el navegador, seguí los pasos de instalación de este link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/como-instalar-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04-es

No se cual pueda ser el error.

Comment: Puedes hacer un `sudo updatedb` y un `locate php7.0-fpm.sock` y verificar que el mismo se encuentre en `/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;` como lo indica el tutorial, si no es así te recomiendo que corrijas el error y lo intentes nuevamente

Comment: Cómo y donde estás declarando el upstream php? Y cómo le envias el request en tus vhosts?

Comment: Hay varios posibles motivos de error. Deberías mostrar la parte de `nginx` en la que indicas `fastcgi_pass`, el trozo del log de `nginx`, posible log de `fpm`, ... algo por donde empezar, vamos.